# new class with method toString()

Tags: java, class, tostring, println

This is related to an earlier question I asked. I'm adding a toString() method to a class. The class creates an arbitrarily long natural number using a stack of integer. I'm only incrementing and decrementing, so stack seemed a good way to go. Anyway, I don't get any output from the following code:

```
public String toString() {
    String out_final = "", backwards = "", temp_str = "";
    Integer temp_int = 0;
    Character temp_char = ' ';

    while(!number.empty()) {
        temp_int = number.pop();
        temp_str = temp_int.toString();
        backwards.concat(temp_str);
    }

    while(backwards.length() > 0) {
        temp_char = backwards.charAt(backwards.length() - 1);
        temp_str = temp_char.toString();
        out_final.concat(temp_str);
    }
    return out_final;
}
```

It is invoked by `System.out.println(b4.toString());`
The object `number` refers to my `Stack<Integer>`
I've gotta take from the end of the stack (obviously in reverse) and then reverse it again to print correctly. Anyway, no hurry on this one, but help is always appreciated!

Comment: You might want to change Integer to int and Character to char as they're both faster and more memory efficient.

Comment: If I wasn't such a java noob, I would. It's working for now, and god knows if I change something simple it'd explode. As always though, I'm lovin' the feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strings are immutable:

```
backwards.concat(temp_str);
```

should be

```
backwards = backwards.concat(temp_str);
```

And the same with the out_final concatenation.

Alternatively, if your stack is fairly large, a [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) may be useful and possibly more efficient to you.

Comment: StringBuilder is the recommended option. StringBuffer is either deprecated or it use is discouraged (deprecated, I think.)

Comment: You've got me on the right track since I'm at least getting output in the right format now. Thank you much :)

Comment: StringBuffer is not deprecated but has some overhead associated to synchronization. StringBuilder is faster and suitable in most cases but not thread-safe.